# What is the difference between the general white process and the white process of order ?

Tags: statistics, random-process

[Antoni](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0888327004001517) uses the following definition of white process of order $p$:

> a process whose all cumulants up to order p are such that
> $$\text{Cum}\left[X(t),X(t-\tau_1)\cdots,X(t-\tau_{r-1})\right]=C_{rX}\delta(\tau_{1})\cdots\delta(\tau_{r-1})\forall
> > r\le p$$
>
> Where $X(t)$ is a random process of time.

I can tell very little about this expression besides that the expression boils down to 0 for any case other than
$\tau_1=..\tau_{r-1}=0$.

What is the difference between the general white process and the white process of order ?

**Comment: This question was originally asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4752147/definition-of-white-process-of-order-p) but did not pull any attention**...

Comment: Listen, besides statistical communication theory, i've also had a couple of courses in probability, random variables, random processes.  I dunno what the author means by "cumulant", but it looks like expectation value.  In the semantic of electrical engineers, we describe "white noise" as having constant power per unit frequency, for ***all*** frequencies.  The integral under the power spectral density curve is infinite. So white noise has infinite power. The autocorrelation function evaluated at the origin is power. But it's $\delta(\tau)$.

Comment: I assume that by cumulant he refers to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulant . @robertbristow-johnson, does it make sense to you?

Comment: Yeah.  So it's the log of the expectation of the exponential of the random number.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson, I am not sure that I am following you. Maybe it is my fault. I have focused my question: "What is the difference between the general white process and the white process of order ?" Do you think that your comment answers this question?

Comment: I don't really get this cumulant thing, because it doesn't seem consistent with what we normally mean by *"white noise"*.  I can explain to you what electrical engineers normally mean by *"white noise"* (and, in comparison to *red* or *brown noise*, *1/f* or *pink noise*).

Comment: I have found [these][https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulant#Joint_cumulants] properties and it seems that if we use the normal distribution property of cumulant=0 for every cumulant higher than 2, it is some kind of generalization - in case we substitute values into the equation - it provides zeros as expected